# Expected value of a function of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a problem that I do not know how to start. I would appreciate a push out the gate.

Please do not supply full workings.

$p(Y=1)=p$, $P(Y=-1)=q=(1-p)$

I need to show that:
 $E( \frac q{p})^Y = 1$

Again, I am just after a start, not the fully worked answer.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Use the definition of expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $E(f(X))=\sum_x f(x)P(X=x)$, just plug in the values you were given into the formula, with $f(x)=a^x$ for some constant $a$.